# Built-in function for assignment in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was having a doubt today :).
For

```
A=1;
```

is there any function `f` that does the same? like following

```
f(A,1);
```

It could help me in some cases like in cellfun or something like that.

Comment: Having side effect in `cellfun` is not a good practice . Use [for loop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) to modify variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily if your variable `A` is a [handle class object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html), thus giving it reference behavior. You could then create a method `f` for the class that accepts a class object `A` and a new value for it to store. See [Object-Oriented Programming](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) for more information.

For data types like `double` or `cell` there are no built-in functions that work this way. You *could* make your own function using [`assignin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) and [`inputname`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) like so:

```
function f(var, value)
  assignin('caller', inputname(1), value);
end
```

And call it as follows, with `A` already defined:

```
A = 0;
f(A, 1);  % Changes the value of A to 1
```

However, this would generally be considered bad practice as it makes the code harder to follow, as call-by-value behavior is the expected norm.

Comment: `A` is simple variable of type double or cell array. i was just having a doubt. as `=` does its job, there must be somekind of a function doing the operation of assignment. for example `+` has `plus`.

Comment: @Sai: Assignment using `=` doesn't have a corresponding function. The closest is [subscripted assignment](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html), but that still requires a modified object be returned.

Comment: I have checked that! Anyhow its interesting. Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 4):

In general no, MATLAB functions cannot change their input.

But, if you are brave, you can [create a MEX-file that breaks that promise and does change the input](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-mex-in-place-editing). In a MEX-file you can write to the input array, but doing so carelessly causes havoc. For example,

```
B = A;
f(A,1); % <- modifies A
```

would cause B to also be modified, because MATLAB delays copying the data when you do `B = A`. That is, the two variables point to the same data until you modify one, at which point the data is copied. But in a MEX-file you can write to a matrix without doing this check, thereby modifying `B` also. The link I provided shows how to modify `A` carefully.

Comment: B value changes even A changes after the assignment?

Comment: If you do `B=A; A(1)=1`, then no, `B` doesn't change. But if you write an uncareful MEX-file that "breaks the promise, you could do `B=A; f(A,1);` and see `B` change.